# ReactFlow Graph doesn't re-render when updated

Tags: reactjs, angular, react-flow

I put a ReactFlow component to my Angular project, that shows the graph perfectly when initializing the component.
Whenever I update the graph e.g. by changing the direction or updating the nodes, the "onLayout" method is called, however the graph won't update.
It will continuously show the first graph.

```
export const CustomReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<AppProps> = ({propNodes,propEdges }: AppProps) => {

  const { nodes: layoutedNodes, edges: layoutedEdges } = getLayoutedElements(
    propNodes,
    propEdges,
    'LR'
  );
   
  const [nodes, setNodes, onNodesChange] = useNodesState(layoutedNodes);
  const [edges, setEdges, onEdgesChange] = useEdgesState(layoutedEdges);

  const onLayout = useCallback(
    (direction) => {
      const { nodes: layoutedNodes, edges: layoutedEdges } = getLayoutedElements(
        propNodes,
        propEdges,
        direction
      );
      
      setNodes([...layoutedNodes]);
      setEdges([...layoutedEdges]);
    },
    [nodes, edges]
  );
  

  return (
    <>
      <div className="layoutflow">
        <ReactFlow
          nodes={layoutedNodes}
          edges={layoutedEdges}
          nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
          onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
          onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
          onConnect={onConnect}
          connectionLineType={ConnectionLineType.SmoothStep}
          style={{ height: 500 }}
          nodesDraggable={true}
          fitView
        />
        <div className="controls"> 
          <button className="w3-button w3-green w3-left-align commonFont" onClick={() => onLayout('TB')}>vertical layout</button>
          <button className="w3-button w3-green w3-left-align commonFont" onClick={() => onLayout('LR')}>horizontal layout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>

  );
};
```

I took most of the code from the React Website.
Does anyone see the problem?

Here is the rest of the code that initializes the graph, which I didn't change:

The component is called in Angular from a Wrapper, by the following function:

```
private render() {
            if(this.graph === undefined){
                console.log("Graph still undefined");
            }else{
                ReactDOM.render(
                    <React.StrictMode>
                        <div>
                            <CustomReactComponent propNodes={this.graph.nodes} propEdges={this.graph.edges}/>
                        </div>
                    </React.StrictMode>
                    , this.containerRef.nativeElement);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Please tag me , If you find : )